# In Power BI import mode, is it possible to only update a part of a table?

Tags: import, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a rather large table in PowerBI, which uses import mode. On each refresh, the update therefore takes quite a lot of time. Since, the rows are based on dates, is it possible that only a part of the table is updated. For example, only update for recent dates, as the data for older dates won't change.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is definitely possible.
You might want to refer to [Incremental Refresh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/incremental-refresh-overview)

By using this you can ask Power BI to refresh only last `n` number of periods (days, months,years) of data to be refreshed only while pulling from a DB or datasource. The historic will still be there but will not get refreshed as they don't need to be refreshed.

It can improve data refresh dramatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can add date filtering in transform data (Power query) for the limited time period, Here you can add filtering in table of if your database is relational database then you can directly add the query to pull data.

Comment: I know about direct query, but don't want to use that.